# Is it possible to make an index of React-native components and pass them conditionally as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, react-native

In React-native, svgs are a mess. I've solved this by using `msvgc` to convert an SVG into a `.tsx` component, which is then exported. It works.

However, I have an entire folder of these components and I'd like to index them so they can be passed conditionally to child components. Think like this: A list of cryptocurrencies needs to be presented. Each card will take a logo(SVG in the form of a `.tsx` component) as a prop. How would this work?

Example, `index.ts`:

```
import BTCLogo from './Bitcoin'
import ETHLogo from './Ethereum'
import DogeLogo from './Doge'

export const cryptoLogos = {
    Doge: DogeLogo,
    BTC: BTCLogo,
    ETH: ETHLogo,
};
```

In a, let's say, `CryptoContainer`, how would I be able to pass these to a child component?

```
import * as logos from './cryptologos'

// I can access them as logos.cryptoLogos but I get the error `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.`?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. You need to wrap your SVGs as JSX components when you index them.

```
export const cryptoLogos = {
    'Doge': <DogeLogo/>,
    'BTC': <BTCLogo/>,
    'ETH': <ETHLogo/>,
};
```